# dataframe pivot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pivot df111 into df222:

[image]
[image]

```
   ID1 ID2 Type  Value
0   1   a    X      1
1   1   a    Y      2
2   1   b    X      3
3   1   b    Y      4
4   2   a    X      5
5   2   a    Y      6
6   2   b    X      7
7   2   b    Y      8



   ID1 ID2  X Value  Y Value
0   1   a        1        2
1   1   b        3        4
2   2   a        5        6
3   2   b        7        8
```

I tried with df111.pivot() and df111.groupby() but no luck. Can someone throw me a one-liner? Thanks

Comment: Please provide actual sample of your dataset instead of images. You can copy-paste the results of `print(df111)` and `print(df222)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pivot_table function, why the hell you provide pivot? this is just confusing ...

```
df333 = pd.pivot_table(df111, index=['ID1','ID2'], columns=['Type'], values='Value')
df333.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by first [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) the three first columns and then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). To fit the exact output, rename the columns by keeping the second level and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) such as:

```
df222 = df111.set_index(['ID1', 'ID2','Type']).unstack()
df222.columns = [col[1] + ' Value' for col in df222.columns]
df222 = df222.reset_index()

print (df222)
   ID1 ID2  X Value  Y Value
0    1   a        1        2
1    1   b        3        4
2    2   a        5        6
3    2   b        7        8
```

and if you want to do it with chaining methods:

```
df222 = df111.set_index(['ID1', 'ID2','Type']).Value.unstack()\
             .rename(columns = {'X': 'X Value', 'Y': 'Y Value'})\ 
             .rename_axis(None, axis="columns")\
             .reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Your answer works, but I like my own answer better.

Answer (score 0):

```
df222 = (df111.set_index(['ID1', 'ID2','Type']).unstack()
     .add_suffix(' Value'))
df222.columns=[lev[1] for lev in df222.columns]
df222.reset_index(inplace=True)
```